# Issues Generating ODB Schema and Query Files for C++ Project

Tags: c++, sqlite, compiler-errors, database-schema, odb

I am working on a C++ project using ODB for database management. I encountered several errors while attempting to generate schema and query files using ODB commands. Here's the command I've been trying:

```
odb --database sqlite --generate-schema --generate-query -I../config -I../communication/toComputer -I../window/patientWindows Patients.hpp
```

I received errors related to missing include files and incorrect directory paths. For example:
`fatal error: global.hpp: No such file or directory`

I've verified the files exist and tried adjusting the include paths without success. Here are the key files and their locations relative to the command execution directory:

- `Patients.hpp` and `Patients.cpp` in `src/database`
- Dependencies in `src/config`, `src/communication/toComputer`, and `src/window/patientWindows`

```
branche/mainApp/src
├── config 
│   ├── global.hpp
├── database
│   ├── Patients.hpp
│   ├── databaseTable.hpp
├── communication
│   └── toComputer
├── window
    └── patientWindows
```

Could someone guide me on the correct way to structure the ODB command with the appropriate include paths, or how to resolve these include file errors?